# Ruby bundle without bundled gems' binaries?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

While I like the idea of using the `bundler` gem to encapsulate dependencies inside my own gem, I haven't been able to figure out some of its [mis]features.

Specifically for this question, when I as `root` install a gem that includes in its bundle other gems that provide binaries, those binaries get installed system-wide, potentially intefering with same-named binaries from other sources.

How do I keep the effects of the bundle specifically within the owning gem's influence?  *I.e.*, not installing things outside of the gem's own unpacked tree?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `--path` argument. [From the documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.6/bundle_install.html):

> Specify a different path than the system default ($BUNDLE_PATH or
>   $GEM_HOME). Bundler will remember this value for future installs on
>   this machine

So as an example:

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

will ensure that your gems will be installed under `vendor/bundle` which will be created relative to your project's root directory.

**Edit:**

When someone installs your gem using bundler using the `--path`, the dependencies of your gem should be installed in the same location `vendor/bundle` mentioned above. It will not install it in a system-wide location.

Comment: So the `rake` binary, for instance, should end up somewhere in my gem's private tree, and not where `gem install rake` would put it?  I'll check this out, thanks!